# Why changes in one branch can affect the other branch in git?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, delete-file

1. I was at master branch,
2. I commit everything
3. then I create a new branch "git checkout -b xxx"
4. then I switch back to master "git checkout master"
5. then I delete everything with master branch without using "git rm"
6. I checkouted to branch xxx, during the branch switching, it shows a long list that every file had a status 'D'
7. then I found the branch xxx had a empty folder too.

It wasn't a problem since I can revert in branch xxx with "gt reset --hard HEAD"

I just wonder why deleting behavior at one branch can affect the other branch? Doesn't the branch stored everything?

Comment: have you commit after delete? Show your `git status` please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 3. then I tried to merge one of my branch using "git merge xxx", it said "alread update to date"

This happen because your *xxx* branch was already merged into *master* and nothing changed in *xxx* after that.

> 4. I checkouted to branch xxx, during the branch switching, it shows a long list that every file had a status 'D'

You haven't commit changes and switched to a branch *xxx*, so all your changes moved to this branch

> I just wonder why deleting behavior at one branch can affect the other branch? Doesn't the branch stored everything?

Yes it does. But you moving your changes between branches without commiting so you could see it in every "up-to-date" branch. Just commit it somewhere and it will behave as expect

**Edit:**
Deletion of files is the same operation as modifying for git, so you have to commit changes *after* delete, somewhere between steps 5 and 6

Comment: I reproduced it, seems if I didn't commit in branch xxx, it is just a point to its parent, so any changes in its parents will reflect in its own branch. Could you mind update your refer than I could accept it ?

Comment: @AlbertGao you are a bit wrong. When you make changes on tracked files(i.e. delete it) it is in *stage* status. Then you are able to move to any "up-to-date" branch and this changes will follow you. Then you can commit it on any "up-to-date" branch and this deletion will affect only on current branch. There is no parent-child relations in git branches, once branch forked out of "parent" it has the same level status as other branches.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, so it means the anything in "stage status" (which I use "git add") will follow me when I change branch?

Comment: @AlbertGao not exactly correct. It works only if your branch is up-to-date with destination branch. If not your "checkout" will be rejected till you commit changes or roll it back or stash it.

Comment: OK, so a bit further, let's say I've added one file, and commit it in both branch A and B, and they just have this only file in each branch, and then I delete this file without using 'git rm' in branch A. So, does branch B still up to date with branch A?

Comment: Before you commit - yes. After - no.

Comment: Hmmm. I haven't mentioned that you do it  *without using 'git rm'*. Ok then  git just behave with it like it's not in stage at all, and drags your changes all over around

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121718/discussion-between-anton-kolyaev-and-albert-gao).

Answer (score 1):

For better understanding of git branches if you use Windows try use application "Git Extensions". This app shows all branches in your repo and it is do understanding simpler.